# Como funciona o arquivo .ret e como aplicá-lo em PHP

Tags: php, boletophp

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde os clientes irão enviar para seus usuários os boletos de pagto. Cada cliente tem seu próprio banco/agência. Irei usar o Boleto PHP e tentar alterar para que se tornem registrados. Porém estou em uma dúvida. Como funciona os arquivos .ret? Eles são o retorno, ou seja, a informação que o cliente pagou, certo? Por ex.: o yii2-boleto-remessa-retorno tem um diretório chamado arquivos, onde entre tantos, tem o arquivo cef.ret.:

```
02RETORNO0000000000000000011119999990000000000000000000000000000000000000000104000000000000000201016000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000002201016         10000000000000000000019101600000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
```

Tentei esse exemplo, mas não funcionou:

```
<?php
    $arquivo = "ret/cef.ret";

    $lendo = fopen($arquivo,"r");
           if (!$lendo){
              echo "Erro ao abrir a URL.";
              exit;
           }
           $i = 0;
           while (!feof($lendo)){
               $i++;
              $linha = fgets($lendo,9999);
              $t_u_segmento = substr($linha,13,1);//Segmento T ou U
              $t_tipo_reg = substr($linha,7,1);//Tipo de Registro
              if($t_u_segmento == 'T'){
                 $t_cod_banco = substr($linha,0,3);//Código do banco na compensação
                 $t_lote = substr($linha,3,4);//Lote de serviço - Número seqüencial para identificar um lote de serviço.
                 $t_n_sequencial = substr($linha,8,5);//Nº Sequencial do registro no lote
                 $t_cod_seg = substr($linha,15,2);//Cód. Segmento do registro detalhe
                 $t_cod_conv_banco = substr($linha,23,6);//Código do convênio no banco - Código fornecido pela CAIXA, através da agência de relacionamento do cliente. Deve ser preenchido com o código do Cedente (6 posições).
                 $t_n_banco_sac = substr($linha,32,3);//Numero do banco de sacados
                 $t_mod_nosso_n = substr($linha,39,2);//Modalidade nosso número
                 $t_id_titulo_banco = substr($linha,41,15);//Identificação do titulo no banco - Número adotado pelo Banco Cedente para identificar o Título.
                 $t_cod_carteira = substr($linha,57,1);//Código da carteira - Código adotado pela FEBRABAN, para identificar a característica dos títulos. 1=Cobrança Simples, 3=Cobrança Caucionada, 4=Cobrança Descontada
                 $t_num_doc_cob = substr($linha,58,11);//Número do documento de cobrança - Número utilizado e controlado pelo Cliente, para identificar o título de cobrança.
                 $t_dt_vencimento = substr($linha,73,8);//Data de vencimento do titulo - Data de vencimento do título de cobrança.
                 $t_v_nominal = substr($linha,81,13);//Valor nominal do titulo - Valor original do Título. Quando o valor for expresso em moeda corrente, utilizar 2 casas decimais.
                 $t_cod_banco2 = substr($linha,96,3);//Código do banco
                 $t_cod_ag_receb = substr($linha,99,5);//Codigo da agencia cobr/receb - Código adotado pelo Banco responsável pela cobrança, para identificar o estabelecimento bancário responsável pela cobrança do título.
                 $t_dv_ag_receb = substr($linha,104,1);//Dígito verificador da agencia cobr/receb
                 $t_id_titulo_empresa = substr($linha,105,25);//identificação do título na empresa - Campo destinado para uso da Empresa Cedente para identificação do Título. Informar o Número do Documento - Seu Número.
                 $t_cod_moeda = substr($linha,130,2);//Código da moeda
                 $t_tip_inscricao = substr($linha,132,1);//Tipo de inscrição - Código que identifica o tipo de inscrição da Empresa ou Pessoa Física perante uma Instituição governamental: 0=Não informado, 1=CPF, 2=CGC / CNPJ, 9=Outros.
                 $t_num_inscricao = substr($linha,133,15);//Número de inscrição - Número de inscrição da Empresa (CNPJ) ou Pessoa Física (CPF).
                 $t_nome = substr($linha,148,40);//Nome - Nome que identifica a entidade, pessoa física ou jurídica, Cedente original do título de cobrança.
                 $t_v_tarifa_custas = substr($linha,198,13);//Valor da tarifa/custas
                 $t_id_rejeicoes = substr($linha,213,10);//Identificação para rejeições, tarifas, custas, liquidação e baixas
              }
              if($t_u_segmento == 'U'){
                 $t_id_titulo_banco;
                 $u_cod_banco = substr($linha,0,3);//Código do banco na compensação
                 $u_lote = substr($linha,3,4);//Lote de serviço - Número seqüencial para identificar um lote de serviço.
                 $u_tipo_reg = substr($linha,7,1);//Tipo de Registro - Código adotado pela FEBRABAN para identificar o tipo de registro: 0=Header de Arquivo, 1=Header de Lote, 3=Detalhe, 5=Trailer de Lote, 9=Trailer de Arquivo.
                 $u_n_sequencial = substr($linha,8,5);//Nº Sequencial do registro no lote
                 $u_cod_seg = substr($linha,15,2);//Cód. Segmento do registro detalhe
                 $u_juros_multa = substr($linha,17,15);//Jurus / Multa / Encargos - Valor dos acréscimos efetuados no título de cobrança, expresso em moeda corrente.
                 $u_desconto = substr($linha,32,15);//Valor do desconto concedido - Valor dos descontos efetuados no título de cobrança, expresso em moeda corrente.
                 $u_abatimento = substr($linha,47,15);//Valor do abat. concedido/cancel. - Valor dos abatimentos efetuados ou cancelados no título de cobrança, expresso em moeda corrente.
                 $u_iof = substr($linha,62,15);//Valor do IOF recolhido - Valor do IOF - Imposto sobre Operações Financeiras - recolhido sobre o Título, expresso em moeda corrente.
                 $u_v_pago = substr($linha,77,15);//Valor pago pelo sacado - Valor do pagamento efetuado pelo Sacado referente ao título de cobrança, expresso em moeda corrente.
                 $u_v_liquido = substr($linha,92,15);//Valor liquido a ser creditado - Valor efetivo a ser creditado referente ao Título, expresso em moeda corrente.
                 $u_v_despesas = substr($linha,107,15);//Valor de outras despesas - Valor de despesas referente a Custas Cartorárias, se houver.
                 $u_v_creditos = substr($linha,122,15);//Valor de outros creditos - Valor efetivo de créditos referente ao título de cobrança, expresso em moeda corrente.
                 $u_dt_ocorencia = substr(substr($linha,137,8),4,4).'-'.substr(substr($linha,137,8),2,2).'-'.substr(substr($linha,137,8),0,2);//Data da ocorrência - Data do evento que afeta o estado do título de cobrança.
                 $u_dt_efetivacao = substr($linha,145,8);//Data da efetivação do credito - Data de efetivação do crédito referente ao pagamento do título de cobrança.
                 $u_dt_debito = substr($linha,157,8);//Data do débito da tarifa
                 $u_cod_sacado = substr($linha,167,15);//Código do sacado no banco
                 $u_cod_banco_comp = substr($linha,210,3);//Cód. Banco Correspondente compens - Código fornecido pelo Banco Central para identificação na Câmara de Compensação, do Banco ao qual será repassada a Cobrança do Título.
                 $u_nn_banco = substr($linha,213,20);//Nosso Nº banco correspondente - Código fornecido pelo Banco Correspondente para identificação do Título de Cobrança. Deixar branco (Somente para troca de arquivos entre Bancos).

                 $u_juros_multa = substr($u_juros_multa,0,13).'.'.substr($u_juros_multa,13,2);
                 $u_desconto = substr($u_desconto,0,13).'.'.substr($u_desconto,13,2);
                 $u_abatimento = substr($u_abatimento,0,13).'.'.substr($u_abatimento,13,2);
                 $u_iof = substr($u_iof,0,13).'.'.substr($u_iof,13,2);
                 $u_v_pago = substr($u_v_pago,0,13).'.'.substr($u_v_pago,13,2);
                 $u_v_liquido = substr($u_v_liquido,0,13).'.'.substr($u_v_liquido,13,2);
                 $u_v_despesas = substr($u_v_despesas,0,13).'.'.substr($u_v_despesas,13,2);
                 $u_v_creditos = substr($u_v_creditos,0,13).'.'.substr($u_v_creditos,13,2);

                 $data_agora = date('Y-m-d');
                 $hora_agora = date('H:i:s');
                 //$insert = "UPDATE financeiro SET valor_pago_fn='$u_v_pago', pagamento_fn='$u_dt_ocorencia', status_fn='Pago', financ_data_fn='$data_agora', financ_hora_fn='$hora_agora', retorno_fn='$nome' WHERE id_fn='$t_id_titulo_banco'";
                 //$query = mysql_query($insert);
              }
           }
           fclose($lendo);
?>
```

Gostaria de saber se esse arquivo .ret é padrão para todos os bancos CEF e se for, como aplicá-lo no meu sistema? Ele varia de conta/agência para conta/agência? Tenho que fazer alguma alteração no boleto de remessa ou terei que criar um novo arquivo para identificar alguma numeração ligada a uma api do banco e alterar o banco de dados como ocorre no PagSeguro por ex?

Baixei [Esses arquivos](https://github.com/manoelcampos/retorno-boletophp), mas pelo que vi, o link da documentação não existe e não consegui entender muito bem como funciona.

Só peço a gentileza de não negativarem ou encararem como duplicata, pois vi em vários posts não só aqui, mas também em outros fóruns que muitas das soluções não foram 100% resolvidas e acredito que se abrirmos um debate para isso, irá ajudar muitos colegas que precisam dessa solução.

Comment: Sim, o arquivo de retorno vai variar de acordo com o convênio do correntista, percebi que teu padrão é 400, que é o antigo, a caixa está utilizando um padrão 240 com duas linhas por boleto. Para o layout 400, veja aqui o manual: https://www.caixa.gov.br/Downloads/cobranca-caixa/Manual_Leiaute_CNAB400_SIGCB.pdf

Comment: Olá IpFranz. Certo. Nesse caso, o correntista terá que fazer o download do arquivo de retorno do banco e depois fazer o upload no meu sistema? Seria isso? Pergunto porque vi em alguns exemplos que existem o retorno automático.

Comment: Exato, e seu sistema deve analisar a situação de cada boleto por meio do nosso número. Meio tosco isso dos bancos, podiam disponibilizar uma API, facilitaria muito as coisas e deixaria o processo mais transparente para o usuário ...

Comment: Quanto a retorno automático, provavelmente é nos sistemas que o próprio banco oferece, não?

Comment: Acredito que sim...